# Vue v-bind not reading data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have to problems with my code... first, the v-bind is not working, it does not add the class and second, when the heartClick is fired, in the alert it only says undefined-undefined-undefined... why?

i got the following code:

```
<svg class="heart" v-on:click="heartClick" v-bind:class="{'heart-pulse': isLike}">

</svg>
```

and in export default i have the following:

```
export default {
data(){
  return{
    map,
    imagenes:['checkIn', 'noCheckIn'],
    checkIneado: false,
    isLike: true,
    test: 'test'
  }
},methods:{
  heartClick: function(){
    alert(this.isLike+"-"+this.checkIneado+"-"+this.test)
    if (this.isLike === true) {
      this.isLike = false;
    }else{
      this.isLike = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the `map` in your `data()`?

Comment: that isnt the problem :( haha... its a instance of google maps

Comment: Is there more information,? And maybe you can put the code in jsFiddle.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this: https://jsfiddle.net/cxm7u09s/. It must be caused by some part of your code you haven't shared